# Golang unmarshal struct with error interface func

Tags: go

I'm trying to do Unmarshal from an struct that is complaint from Error Interface, but when i'm trying to get the Res structure Error content, it return the Error Interface string instead.

> Example(with Error Interface complain): https://play.golang.org/p/ZZDTMSXYO7

Result: `2009/11/10 23:00:00   C: -> {Data:{Title:Lorem Ipsum data} Error:}`

> Example(Without Error Interface complain): https://play.golang.org/p/VmS0xIglC0

Expected: `2009/11/10 23:00:00     C: -> {Data:{Title:Lorem Ipsum data} Error:{Title:Lorem Ipsum error}}`

Can anyone help us on this?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? You're creating an `Error() string` method which only returns and empty string, but complaining that it returns and empty string.

Comment: You are aware that the first example unmarshals correctly, you're just not printing the Error value? https://play.golang.org/p/g5tMmdjCC3

Comment: Why even use your own custom Error type, why not just use the builtin error type?

Answer (score 3):

`log.Printf` with the `%+v` formatting calls the `Error` method on a value that implements the `error` interface, which is the case with your `Error` type. So instead of printing the value's contents it prints the string that the `Error` method returns, which is an empty string in your example.

But that does not mean that the unmarshaler didn't unmarshal the json properly and you can see that by changing the formatting verb to `%#v` or by printing just the `Title` field.

https://play.golang.org/p/PgFCDnySb9